# How to include custom types/namespaces in typescript compilation build

Tags: typescript, types, compilation, reference, namespaces

I am building a typescript library to be used by other projects.

I have some modules in it which reference types and interfaces from several namespaces under the main library namespace. They are declared in `d.ts` files in a root `@types` folder included in the `typeRoots` of `tsconfig.json`.

Everything works fine in the IDE during development, tests and at compile time, no errors.

The problem is once compiled in `dist` folder, while my namespaces are still referenced in generated modules `d.ts` files, the actual `d.ts` files referencing them are nowhere to be found, making the resultant compiled library unusable (raising a "TS2503: error Cannot find namespace" if I try to use it elsewhere).

How would one is supposed to make its custom namespaces included by typescript compilation in the resulting build ?

Folder structure :

```
├── _@types
│   ├── main_namespace
│   │   ├── sub_namespace
|   |   |   └── index.d.ts
│   │   └── index.d.ts
│   └── index.d.ts
├── src
│   ├── module1
│   │   └── index.ts
│   ├── module2
│   │   └── index.ts
│   └── module3
│       ├── index.ts
│       ├── submodule1.ts
│       └── submodule2.ts
├── test
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "lib": [
      "esnext"
    ],
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist/@types",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "typeRoots": [
      "@types",
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "@types",
    "src"
  ]
}
```